# Preserving column name order to_dict

Tags: python, pandas

How can I preserve the order of the header name. The order isn't alphabetically, it is a custom order. It's fine in the dataframe but when I do `to_dict` the order isn't what I originally had.

This is in a method I have in class.

```
 #the list is much larger
 income_statements = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Year', 'Operating_Revenue', 'COGS','Income_Tax', 'Total_Revenue')

for year in years:
            url = 'financials/standardized?identifier='+symbol+'&statement=income_statement&type=QTR&fiscal_year='+str(year)+'&date='+date
            fin_data = requests.get(self.get_intrino+url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(intrino_uname, intrino_pw)).json()['data']
            row = []
            row.append(year)
            for i in range(len(fin_data)):
                row.append( fin_data[i]['value'] )
            income_statements.loc[len(income_statements)] = row
```

I then call it.. this is just an example but I take the return of my method
`income_statements.to_dict()`

It ends up showing 'Income_Tax' first instead of 'Year'. Is there a way to preserve the header column names?

Comment: no, dict key order is inherently unordered, you'd have to use something like an `OrderedDict` and construct this yourself

Comment: @EdChum okay, thats a bummer but will do. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using Python 3.7+, dictionaries are assumed to be unordered. A workaround is to sort and then feed into `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

df_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(df_dict.items(), key=lambda x: df.columns.get_loc(x[0])))
```

`pd.DataFrame.columns.get_loc` returns the integer location of a column. We assume keys of `df_dict` are columns.